# erron in flutter package publishing `LICENSE` file contains generic TODO. pub finished with exit code 1

Tags: dart, publish

when running command:

```
dart pub publish --dry-run
```

Response :

```
Resolving dependencies... 
  async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
  characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)
  collection 1.17.0 (1.18.0 available)
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
  lints 2.0.1 (2.1.1 available)
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.1 available)
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
  stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
  stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.6.1 available)
Got dependencies!
Publishing responsive_card 0.0.1 to https://pub.dev:
|-- CHANGELOG.md (<1 KB)
|-- LICENSE (<1 KB)
|-- README.md (1 KB)
|-- analysis_options.yaml (<1 KB)
|-- android
|   |-- app
|   |   '-- src
|   |       '-- main
|   |           '-- java
|   |               '-- io
|   |                   '-- flutter
|   |                       '-- plugins
|   |                           '-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java (<1 KB)
|   '-- local.properties (<1 KB)
|-- assets
|   |-- in desktop.png (171 KB)
|   '-- in mobile.png (179 KB)
|-- ios
|   |-- Flutter
|   |   |-- Generated.xcconfig (<1 KB)
|   |   '-- flutter_export_environment.sh (<1 KB)
|   '-- Runner
|       |-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h (<1 KB)
|       |-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift (<1 KB)
|       '-- ephemeral
|           |-- Flutter-Generated.xcconfig (<1 KB)
|           '-- flutter_export_environment.sh (<1 KB)
|-- pubspec.yaml (1 KB)
|-- test
|   '-- responsive_card_test.dart (<1 KB)
'-- windows
    '-- flutter
        |-- generated_plugin_registrant.cc (<1 KB)
        |-- generated_plugin_registrant.h (<1 KB)
        '-- generated_plugins.cmake (<1 KB)

Package has 0 warnings.                  
The server may enforce additional checks.
```

After running publish:

```
dart pub publish
```

response :

```
Resolving dependencies... 
  async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
  characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)              
  collection 1.17.0 (1.18.0 available)            
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)                      
  lints 2.0.1 (2.1.1 available)                   
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)             
  material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.1 available)                    
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
  stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
  stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.6.1 available)
Got dependencies!
Publishing responsive_card 0.0.1 to https://pub.dev:
|-- CHANGELOG.md (<1 KB)
|-- LICENSE (<1 KB)
|-- README.md (1 KB)
|-- analysis_options.yaml (<1 KB)
|-- android
|   |-- app
|   |   '-- src
|   |       '-- main
|   |           '-- java
|   |               '-- io
|   |                   '-- flutter
|   |                       '-- plugins
|   |                           '-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java (<1 KB)
|   '-- local.properties (<1 KB)
|-- assets
|   |-- in desktop.png (171 KB)
|   '-- in mobile.png (179 KB)
|-- ios
|   |-- Flutter
|   |   |-- Generated.xcconfig (<1 KB)
|   |   '-- flutter_export_environment.sh (<1 KB)
|   '-- Runner
|       |-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h (<1 KB)
|       '-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m (<1 KB)
|-- lib
|   |-- responsive_card.dart (<1 KB)
|   '-- src
|       '-- responsive_card.dart (2 KB)
|-- linux
|   '-- flutter
|       |-- generated_plugin_registrant.cc (<1 KB)
|       |-- generated_plugin_registrant.h (<1 KB)
|       '-- generated_plugins.cmake (<1 KB)
|-- macos
|   '-- Flutter
|       |-- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift (<1 KB)
|       '-- ephemeral
|           |-- Flutter-Generated.xcconfig (<1 KB)
|           '-- flutter_export_environment.sh (<1 KB)
|-- pubspec.yaml (1 KB)
|-- test
|   '-- responsive_card_test.dart (<1 KB)
'-- windows
    '-- flutter
        |-- generated_plugin_registrant.cc (<1 KB)
        |-- generated_plugin_registrant.h (<1 KB)
        '-- generated_plugins.cmake (<1 KB)

Publishing is forever; packages cannot be unpublished.
Policy details are available at https://pub.dev/policy

Do you want to publish responsive_card 0.0.1 to https://pub.dev (y/N)? y
Uploading... (3.1s)
`LICENSE` file contains generic TODO.
```

I'm getting **LICENSE file contains generic TODO.** error help me. is there any way to solve this issue? after I login a to my gmail this occures. after I login a to my gmail this occures. after I login a to my gmail this occures.after I login a to my gmail this occures.after I login a to my gmail this occures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit root/licence

```
TODO: Add your license here.
```

add licence here as like.

```
    Boost Software License - Version 1.0 - August 17th, 2003

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or organization
obtaining a copy of the software and accompanying documentation covered by
this license (the "Software") to use, reproduce, display, distribute,
execute, and transmit the Software, and to prepare derivative works of the
Software, and to permit third-parties to whom the Software is furnished to
do so, all subject to the following:

The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement, including
the above license grant, this restriction and the following disclaimer,
must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole or in part, and
all derivative works of the Software, unless such copies or derivative
works are solely in the form of machine-executable object code generated by
a source language processor.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT
SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE
FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

you can use github licence template as well